# Math accessibility for math kids on Android via Gboard (or other comfortable math keyboard) via plugins and software engineering

Tags: android, math, text-processing, latex, accessibility

I tried posting this on the TeX - LaTeX stack exchange, but couldn't because I kept getting an error (I couldn't identify the error).

I am looking for a predictive system I want to use on Android to type text and get latex command output by hooking into latex command syntax via latex command prediction (based on text input).

For instance,

If I type on Gboard

d by dx

The system infers

\frac{d}{dx}

and displays the latex output as a button to press (in the area below Gboard). This is installed and then displayed as a plugin.

As you continue typing you can select (for instance even where in a fraction you are typing).

It you type (the nth root) and you get a button with a typeset.

If you type under the square root, a fraction, gboard suggests with a cursor on a button if the next part to be typed is on the top part of the fraction, the bottom part, or a continuation.

There can be many software plugins that can be developed as plugins for this, as incremental versions.

There can be either even buttons to align equations.

And there can be blank buttons to steal keys from language keyboards via a special steal and place below key (via a menu it is also possible to remove a key, move it, or change the order of keys. Scrolling may even be allowed.

All off amslatex amsmath amssty and so on should be available.

If you currently long press the comma on Gboard, you can shift it above. So the space for bookmarked keys from languages and special math operator symbols like \mathplus or \rightarrow exist (these can be scrolled, along with bookmarked symbols, as said).

As I said, there has to be a Gboard support infrastructure. We want mathematicians to add Unicode math
symbol adding from whatever language they want to write their math proofs or text in, so it makes sense to add to Gboard.

The recipient application, receives the Unicode text or commands from the Gboard with Gboard plugin, and typesets it in ASCII or PDF depending on the receiving renderer.

We need this, because baby kids, especially tired kids, will be doing math in bed (and we don't want them to just copy, or read. We want them to actually type things out to gain familiarity and expertise with math by typing it out, and thinking about the steps (which many software such as PhotoMath for Android already do automatically).

We want them to think, and, develop, their own math mechanics.

But we don't want to give them the burden of having to sit in front of the computer and type latex for simple math.

Is anyone willing to please support these kids in their math endeavors?

Where can I find the desired functionality?

Thanks.